# Remove gnome startup animation

Tags: gnome

I had installed gnome using `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop`.

Now I have uninstalled gnome but the gnome animation at startup and shutdown still remains. Also Ubuntu's default **purple color** at the initial screen was changed to **gray** when I had installed gnome.

This color is still gray even after the uninstall. How can I restore the animation and color back to the default?

Answer (score 0):

I could have put in comment, don't have enough rep.
If you exactly want what you say, I may not be able to help.

You can still give **geeky look** to your booting process by using

> xdiagnose

search it in dash.

There can tick

> display boot messages

And in workaround sections, tick

> disable bootloader graphics
>
> disable VESA framebuffer driver
>
> diable PAT memory

You can hover over tick-boxes to see the benefits, overall you will get much stable experience and improved booting.

Answer (score 0):

The startup animation and logo are stored in 
/use/share/plymouth/themes.
Your gnome theme might still be there.
First open your "greeter settings".
If you are using "light-desktop-manager", it will be "LightDM GTK+ Greeter settings"
Open it and then change your greeter theme and icons and logo etc.
Then you can delete that gnome theme from plymouth folder if you want.

This should do!

Answer (score 0):

Run in terminal

```
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
```

and select Ubuntu plymouth theme and then run

`sudo update-initramfs -u`

Reboot to see your changes